# Using an ion page as the content of an ion modal

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic + React to create an app. In the [docs for ion-modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal), it is said that

> In most scenarios, setting a ref on IonPage and passing that ref's current value to presentingElement is fine

However, I am not sure how to do this. If I just pass the IonPage component as the children of the modal it works fine, but there is a weird transition (the modal tries to go from bottom to top but the ion page tries to go from right to left). So I am not sure if using this ref on the Ion Page would solve this particular issue.

Comment: can you please elaborate what you are trying to build , there might be another solution